# SQL Code to Select to select unique column and match with row on another column

Tags: sql

Not even how to word this question:  I have a table that looks like this:

select * from tblServiceUsers
ORDER By ServiceID

```
0   B88230BB-4943-4C10-AB0E-8ABB88A357A3
0   5653C943-7F9A-4746-B2A3-1160E9204A7E
0   08678EE7-49A7-4F63-BC39-CFCCE2C9AD65
1   B88230BB-4943-4C10-AB0E-8ABB88A357A3
1   5653C943-7F9A-4746-B2A3-1160E9204A7E
2   B88230BB-4943-4C10-AB0E-8ABB88A357A3
2   5653C943-7F9A-4746-B2A3-1160E9204A7E
```

And I need a query that only returns the top (or first) userid that matches a serviceID.
For example, I just want 1 UserID to be displayed for each ServiceID.  Such as the following:

```
0   B88230BB-4943-4C10-AB0E-8ABB88A357A3
1   B88230BB-4943-4C10-AB0E-8ABB88A357A3
2   B88230BB-4943-4C10-AB0E-8ABB88A357A3
```

Comment: Please try to format this legibly, using the code formatter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say which version of SQL server it is, but for MS SQL Server 2005 onwards you can do something like :

```
 Select SecID, ServiceID, UserID from 
 (
    select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ServiceID ORDER BY Secid) AS row_number,
    SecID,
    ServiceID,
    UserID
    From tblSecServiceUsers
 ) 
 tempTable
 where row_number = 1
```

Comment: Yes, it's 2005.  I tried this out and it works great!  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use TOP 1 and an ORDER BY clause?

Comment: top 1 will only return 1 row. I have columns ServiceID, and UserID. There are some ServiceID's that have up to 5 userid's, but I only want to display one userid per unique serviceid.

Answer (score 0):

You sound like you're not too bothered which UserId you just want any one? If so this would work.

```
SELECT MAX(UserID) AS UserID, ServiceID  
 FROM tblServiceUsers 
GROUP BY ServiceID 
ORDER BY ServiceID
```